# Unintuitive interpretation of probabilities when doing logistic regression

Tags: probability, distributions, logistic, classification, data-mining

The observations in my dataset can be split in two classes. The observations in class 1 are for sure correctly labeled. The observations that has been designated to class 2 have a huge percentage of mislabeled data. I also know that there are as much mislabeled data in class 2 as there are observations in class 1. As an example I did a small simulation of a potential dataset, to simplify things I only simulated 1 variable and I just copied class 1 observations as the mislabeled class 2 observations. (Note that the true dataset is much larger and contains multiple variables but the problem remains the same and this simulation captures the essence.)

```
Class1 = rnorm(1000,0)
Class2 = c(rnorm(1000,10),Class1)

Class1 = data.frame(score = Class1,Class1 = TRUE)  
Class2 = data.frame(score = Class2,Class1 = FALSE)  
dat = rbind(Class1,Class2)
```

My goal is to decide which observations in class 2 are truly from class 2 and which should have been in class 2. Since I have multiple variables I decided to fit a logistic regression model on my data and use the probabilities as a metric to decide if the observations of class 2 are mislabeled or not.

```
fit = glm(Class1~.,data= dat, family = binomial)
hist(fit$fitted.values,xlim = c(0,1),xlab = "P(Class 1)",
     main='Histogram of probabilities of being in Class 1' )
```

[image: Imgur]

If you plot the probabilities in the histogram, you see a lot of observations around 0. These are probably the true class 2 observations. You can also see a lot of observations around .5. This makes sense. You know that there are as many observations in class 1 as there are mislabeled observations in class 2. So if you see an observation with a parameter value that comes from the 'class 1' distribution, you can have 50 percent probability that is has a class 1 label and 50 percent probability that is has an class 2 label (so mislabeled).

But I find the above distribution of probabilities shown in the histogram somehow peculiar. I would have expected that all values would be between 0 and 0.5. Instead I also see some values for example around .6. So if I see an observations with these variable values I'm 60 percent sure it belongs to class 1. How can this be? In my simulation example I just copied the same values for class 1 and the mislabeled class 2, so above observation should in theory not be possible.

How should I interpret this? Are these probabilities meaningful?

EDIT:
In response to @whuber I also added the following plot of the data.

```
plot(dat); curve(1/(1 + exp(-coef(fit) %*% rbind(1, x))), add=TRUE)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: (1) Your code won't work because it refers to nonexistent variables like `C1`. (2) Plotting your data is always useful. Try, for instance, `plot(dat);
curve(1/(1 + exp(-coef(fit) %*% rbind(1, x))), add=TRUE)`.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for replying and notifying the wrong code! It's fixed now. I also added the plot you requested but I'm not entirely sure what to make of it.

Comment: The plot shows the model you fit to your data; all the results are a consequence. Your two histograms correspond to the ranges of levels of the curve in the two regions to the left ("class 2") and right ("class 1") of $5$. The curve must pass very close to the point $(0,1/2)$ because you split a large set of data averaging $0$ into the two classes. The curve has to flow continuously in a decreasing manner from left to right. These qualitative characteristics are easily predictable before ever fitting the model--you don't need any software to draw the curve.

Comment: @whuber : Your explanation is indeed logical. But is then there something off with the textbook definition of the probabilities you estimate with logistic regression? This is defined as P(Class 1 | X=x) in my case. If you look eg the value -1 in the plot above, you see an estimated probability of around 0.6. I would have expected 0.5 according the definition P(Class 1 | X=x) since there is in reality equal change of have this value in class 1 and class 2.

Comment: @statastic: ... or is then there something off with your model?

Comment: I believe you may be reasoning with two different, contradictory models. Your argument assumes that variation of `score` around the mean for each class (0 and 10) has no influence at all on the log odds of class inclusion, whereas the model explicitly supposes the log odds are a linear function of the score.  The model used in your argument is the model used to generate the data *but it is not the model used to fit the data.*

Comment: @whuber : woow! thanks for the eye opener! You are right. I tried to fit a more flexible model (with splines) and now I can see that hard "cut - off" at 0.5 probability I was looking for. Too bad I can't flag a comment as an answer. :)

Comment: @statastic: You can use Bayes' Theorem to calculate $\Pr(\mathrm{Class1} |X=x)$ & compare that to fitted models: `dnorm(score)*(1/3) / (dnorm(score)*(1/3) + (dnorm(score,10)/2 + dnorm(score)/2)*(2/3))` I think

Comment: @Scortchi: Yes, I did excactly this. :) Off course I will not be able to do this on my real dataset set so I have to trust this. But I can test with simulated data when the model holds as I need these probabilities for downstream calculations.

Comment: Although I did not intend that comment as an answer, since it seems to have resolved your question, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be reasoning with two different, contradictory models. The argument (in comments to the question) assumes that variation of score around the mean for each class ($0$ and $10$) has no influence at all on the log odds of class inclusion, whereas the model explicitly supposes the log odds are a linear function of the score. The model used in that argument is the model used to generate the data *but it is not the model used to fit the data.*

There's nothing the matter with most of this approach: it actually can be a good idea to generate data in a way that differs from what the model expects, because that can help you assess the model's robustness to violation of assumptions.  Just be sure to keep the distinction between the *actual data generation process* and the *assumptions of the model fitting process* clearly in mind, and all should be OK.